# Fixed point Hamiltonian for a finite system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization

Usually when discussing renormalization in statistical physics, some transformation $R$ of the Hamiltonian is defined, and it is supposed that such a transformation has a fixed point $H^*$ such that $R(H^*)=H^*$. I don't understand what this might mean in finite dimension. Suppose I have an Ising model on $N$ spins

$$ H(s)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{N-1}s_{i,j}s_{i+1,j}+s_{i,j}s_{i,j+1}$$
suppose for the sake of argument that this itself is the "fixed" point of some transformation (I know it's not, but bear with me), then it would mean, I guess, $R(H)=H$, but the renormalized system is defined on *less* spins, $N'=N/b$, would it be correct to say the following?
$$R(H)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{N/b-1}s_{i,j}s_{i+1,j}+s_{i,j}s_{i,j+1} $$

In what sense is this the "same" Hamiltonian? It is clearly a function defined on less variables, so it is not the same function. How to understand the fixed point with finite systems?

For a more general picture you could consider

$$ H(s)=\sum_k q_k h_k(s)$$
where $h_k(s)$ are functions of the spins. It is usually said that after renormalization we can express the new Hamiltonian as the old one with renormalized parameters

$$ R(H)(s)=\sum_k q'_k h_k(s)$$

and the fixed point is just the $q_k$ such that $q_k'=q_k$. But I don't know how to make sense of this, since the function $h_k$ cannot be the same before and after renormalization for the reasons I explained above! Should I take this to mean

$$ R(H)(s)=\sum_k q_k' h'_k(s)$$

where $h'_k(s)$ "has the same form" as $h_k(s)$? In what sense?

Comment: From where do you come to the conclusion that the new Hamiltonian should have fewer degrees of freedom than the new one?

Comment: @Void I'm thinking of real space renormalization of the Ising model (or other lattice models), decimation or block spin procedures for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have true renormalization group (RG) fixed points in finite systems. You need infinitely many degrees of freedom in order to restore the system to its original scale---as you identify in your example, you would be missing terms in a finite system.

Think of it as a kind of reverse [Hilbert Hotel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel): you have a hotel with infinitely many guests, and all of the guests in odd numbered rooms check out. How can you move the remaining guests around so that the hotel is full again? The answer is to move the guest in room $2n$ to room $n$. You could still do this reassignment (tantamount to the rescaling step of the RG procedure) in a finite hotel of $N$ rooms, but you would be left with $\lceil N/2 \rceil$ empty rooms---you can never fill the hotel back to capacity (ignoring the fact that at a real hotel news guests could check in...).

One important thing to note that this analogy applies to the situation in which your original Hamiltonian is already at the fixed point. If you are not at the fixed point already, each RG step will generate new terms in your Hamiltonian that weren't there initially, and it is only under infinitely many repetitions of the RG procedure that "irrelevant" couplings in your Hamiltonian would vanish. Of course, if the original Hamiltonian is not tuned to the critical manifold, the RG procedure will eventually take you to one of the stable fixed points, not the critical point associated with a phase transition, although the RG flow in coupling-space may pass close to the critical point.

All this said, if the initial size of your system is large enough you could still perform the RG procedure many times, anticipating that the terms that disappear due to involving interactions between more degrees of freedom than you have left would be negligible anyways, and you could track the RG flow of the remaining couplings until you get to a point where you cannot reasonably perform another step. (A rough rule of thumb might be to coarsen a system with $N = 2^M$ degrees of freedom down to $N' = 2^{M/2}$, for example). This could give you an estimate of the RG flow that you would obtain in an infinite system.

This is all related to the statement that you cannot have phase transitions in finite systems---you need an infinite number of degrees of freedom to develop a non-analyticity in the free energy, which requires summing up infinitely many terms in the partition function. Similarly, you need to be able to perform infinitely many RG steps in order for the non-analyticity to arise. Of course, we know that in practice we observe phenomena that look like phase transitions despite not being infinite. Water still freezes, after all. Performing the RG procedure on a large enough finite system is similar to computing the heat capacity of a system large enough to observe a narrow---but still smooth---peak in the heat capacity at a particular temperature.